# Xamarin Forms 5.0 TabbedPage Tab Title Text Customization in AndroidX

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, androidx, tabbedpage

I am working on a Xamarin Forms App. Requirement is to make Title of the Tab Pages to Letter-Case + use custom font.

As you can see in [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/38e1f347-8a56-4e8c-8957-8d2d8c8bddb3/tabbedpage-text-issue-in-android?forum=xamarinforms) article, I found some solutions in which styling changes are required in the file Resources/layout/Tabbar.xml to achieve the desired result.

But, Unfortunately Xamarin Forms 5.0 uses AndroidX and REMOVED Resources/layout directory from default creation. And also removed these 2 lines of code from Android Project's MainActivity.cs:

```
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar; // Removed in AndroidX and Xamarin Forms Ver 5.0
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;  // Removed in AndroidX and Xamarin Forms Ver 5.0
```

As you can see in Xamarin official documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/troubleshooting/questions/forms5-migration)

Now I am curious how to do custom styling on TabbedPage Title Text in updated XAMARIN FORMS version 5.0 with AndroidX? Any Idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you read the article you link to, it doesn't tell you to remove it if you are customizing the appearance. In such cases you should edit your layouts to use AndroidX types instead.

So you will need to use `androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar` for your Toolbar in your layout and `com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout` for your TabLayout if you want to customize it.

Comment: What do you mean with "Not worked"? Did you get any error messages, the appearance didn't change, something else? I can't read your intention from your comment here.

Comment: The appearance didn't change

Comment: Well it is unclear why if you don't provide the layout that you are using

Comment: unable to insert images in question due to less reputation points of stackoverflow

Comment: Don't use images, just add the code directly in your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep the  `TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;` in your MainActivity.

And the `Tabbar.xml` like:

```
<com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:background="?android:attr/colorPrimary"
   android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
   ...
   app:tabTextAppearance="@style/MyCustomTextAppearance"  //make your title to Letter-Case 

/>
```

then define the `MyCustomTextAppearance` style in your `Resources/styles`

```
<style name="MyCustomTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
     <item name="textAllCaps">false</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Already applied. No effect on appearance.

Comment: @FahadAliQureshi It works on my side,the letters from all uppercase to case.

Comment: Which Xamarin Forms version you are using?

Comment: @FahadAliQureshi i use the version 5.0.0.2083.